# Matplotlib - align centre monthly width barchart without overlap

Tags: date, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis

I'm plotting two sets of monthly values on one figure, one in line format, the other in bars.

I want to bars to be one month wide so that there are no gaps between them, and the ticks, points, and bars to all be centred.  I can do this, but the bars then overlap slightly due to the differing lengths of the months (largest difference obviously seen in Feb-Mar)

Is there some sort of hack to get around this?
Thanks!

Comment: You should probably provide a minimal example of what you are trying to do, and why it isn't working. Right now we can only guess...

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply, I realise now that I wasn't very clear.  I managed to put together a work around in the end whereby instead of plotting [x, y] (where x is a month and y a value) I ended up plotting [arrange(0, len(y)), y] and assigning custom labels to the 'x' axis using the array  [arrange(0, len(y)), x].  This allowed me to centre the bars with a constant width and have the labels that I wanted.